# How to find supported values of fields in pod spec

Tags: kubernetes

What is the command to view supported values of `operator` field in `pods.spec.tolerations.operator` through command line?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `Kubectl explain pods.spec.tolerations.operator` ?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to figure out the values of the field like `operator`, `effect`, after looking at `kubectl explain --recursive` command.

Answer (score 1):

Found that
`kubectl explain pod.spec.tolerations`

will provide all the allowed values and default values.